# How to declare and use a 2-D int array of size [16][256] in C considering the limited RAM space.?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, bit-manipulation, avr, avr-gcc

I am using avr-8 bit MCU. It has a RAM size of 2K.
I have to declare and use a variable of int of size [16][256]. The int on this machine is 2 bytes. This array will consume 2*16*256 = 8k. This size is not acceptable as I have only 2K RAM.

I have to use this 2-D array to store the status of the flash memory pages that are being written. This array will take 1 or 0 values. 1 means page in flash memory is written and 0 means page in flash memory is not written.

I am looking for solution on how to store this status. Not sure if Bit-fields are helpful here.

Comment: The correct solution may depend on why your array needs to be 2d. If only one of the 16 subarrays needs to be in memory at a time, that may be your solution. The only reasons that bitfields may be inappropriate here is if your code needs to be fast, or needs to conform to an interface.

Comment: you could try using a bit array rather than a int array.  That would reduce the array size to .5k.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to use the array to store boolean data, you do not need the whole 16 bit per field.

To store 16*256 bits you only need 512 bytes.

The makros in the following example can be used to access the values in an 16 x N buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BIT_ISSET(a, x, y)      ((a[x] &  (1<<y))!=0)
#define BIT_SET(a, x, y)         (a[x] |= (1<<y))
#define BIT_CLEAR(a, x, y)       (a[x] &= (1<<y)^0xffff)

int main()
{
    uint16_t values[256] = {0};

    // set some bits
    BIT_SET(values, 3, 0);
    BIT_SET(values, 3, 1);
    BIT_SET(values, 3, 2);
    BIT_SET(values, 3, 3);
    BIT_SET(values, 3, 15);

    // clear one of the previously set bits
    BIT_CLEAR(values, 3, 2);

    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<256;i++) { // 256 rows
        for (j=0;j<16;j++) { // 16 columns
            printf("%i", BIT_ISSET(values, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am glad you answered. What does %i print ? It should print True or false as BIT_ISSET() is returning an expression right? For BIT_CLEAR(), Can I use a[x] &= ~(1<<y) ?

Comment: The %i is there to display a "1" for every set bit (true) and a "0" for every unset bit (false). You could also write 

    `printf("%c", BIT_ISSET(values, i, j) ? 'X' : 'O');` 

The loop just dumps the complete bit array in 256 rows and 16 columns to demonstrate the usage of BIT_ISSET. Yes, you can also use the bitwise inverter for clearing a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bits instead of array. You need only 256*16 bit. So 256*16/8 = 384 byte is enough. You can use char array for this and make bit operations for saving values: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: If I declare as char a [16][256], it will be of size 16*256 = 4K. How come it is just 384 byte. How do I declare 16*256 bits ?

Comment: 256*16/8 = 512, not 384.